# Sort array of objects based on a particular key recursively: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects with the following format:

```
var test = [
  {
    value: "Others",
    parentId: "",
    label: "Others",
    children: [
      {
        value: "user12",
        parentId: "Others",
        label: "bdefault51"
      },
      {
        value: "user11",
        parentId: "Others",
        label: "adefault50"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "Local",
    parentId: "",
    label: "local",
    children: [
      {
        value: "user56",
        parentId: "local",
        label: "bserver"
      },
      {
        value: "user78",
        parentId: "local",
        label: "aserver"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "Lab1",
    parentId: "",
    label: "lab1",
    children: [
      {
        value: "user157",
        parentId: "ent1",
        label: "enterprise45"
      },
      {
        value: "user139",
        parentId: "ent1",
        label: "enterprise37"
      },
      {
        value: "user136",
        parentId: "ent1",
        label: "enterprise56"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Output

```
 [
  {
    value: "Lab1",
    parentId: "",
    label: "lab1",
    children: [
      {
        value: "user139",
        parentId: "ent1",
        label: "enterprise37"
      },
      {
        value: "user157",
        parentId: "ent1",
        label: "enterprise45"
      },
      {
        value: "user136",
        parentId: "ent1",
        label: "enterprise56"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "Local",
    parentId: "",
    label: "local",
    children: [
      {
        value: "user78",
        parentId: "local",
        label: "aserver"
      },
      {
        value: "user56",
        parentId: "local",
        label: "bserver"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: "Others",
    parentId: "",
    label: "Others",
    children: [
      {
        value: "user11",
        parentId: "Others",
        label: "adefault50"
      },
      {
        value: "user12",
        parentId: "Others",
        label: "bdefault51"
      },   
    ]
  }
];
```

I need to sort the objects based on the property `label`. The children can go upto `n` levels, there also the sorting needs to be done by `label`.

Code I tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  test[i].children.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.label - a.label;
  });
}

//Tried with lodash also
let sorted = _.sortBy(test,"label");
let sorted1 = _.orderBy(test,"label","asc");
console.log(test);
```

Comment: What do you expect `b.label - a.label` to be for e.g. `"bdefault51" - "adefault50"`?

Comment: So what is the issue? Are you saying that children can have children? You probably want `return a.label.localeCompare(b.label)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recurcive approach and iterate the given array and their children properties.

```
const
    sort = array => {
        array.sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label));
        array.forEach(({ children = [] }) => sort(children));
    };
```

Comment: nice very nice :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all: you are trying to sort string like numbers. That's why it isn't working. Change `b.label - a.label` to `b.label > a.label` and it must work (simple solution):

```
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  test[i].children = test[i].children.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.label > a.label;
  });
}
```

If you need more advanced sorting possibilites: use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method to compare the strings.

**But generally it is bad approach to modify the existing array.**

The better solution is to create a recursive sorting function and use it to create new sorted array:

```
function sortArray(arr, key) {
  return arr
    .map(item => ({
      ...item,
      children: sortArray(item.children || [], key)
    }))
    .sort((a, b) => b[key] > a[key]);
}

const sortedArray = sortArray(test, "label");
```